# Cakephp 3 unauthorizedRedirect not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I'm doing a page trying to set the unauthorizedRedirect for the auth component in the AppController and is not working, it does nothing.

i have tried putting it on false and nothing works

This is the app controller

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Seems like you have to use some kind of magic word.',
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'unauthorized'
        ],
    ]);

    //use model companies in all controllers
    $tableCategories = $this->loadModel('Categories');

    $categories = $tableCategories->find()
        ->contain([]);

    $this->set(compact('categories'));
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
}
```

}

this is UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController
```

{
    var $breadcrump = 'Usuarios';

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'unauthorized']);
}

public function login()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('login');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function unauthorized()
{
    var_dump();
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $message = false;

    echo json_encode($message);exit;
}
```

it only redirects to the login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html)

> `unauthorizedRedirect` 
>   Controls handling of unauthorized access. By default unauthorized user is redirected to the referrer URL or loginAction or ‘/’. If set to false, a ForbiddenException exception is thrown instead of redirecting.

The `unauthorizedRedirect` option only applies to authenticated users. If an authenticated user tries to go to a URL they are not authorized to access, they will be redirected back to the referrer. By specifying `unauthorizedRedirect`, you are now redirecting the User to the URL specified rather than to referrer.

If you want to redirect user on a wrong login attempt, you will have to do that manually in the login method.

Hope that clears any doubts.

Comment: i'm trying to make a redirect when the not registered users try to access to some page that are restricted to see if you're not registered, the wrong login attempt is working fine

Comment: @EnriqueOquendo As stated in answer, unautorizedRedirect only handles Logged In Users. If a non Logged In User tries to access a Restricted Page, he will always be redirected to Login Page (loginAction) . This can not be customized.